# ¿Cómo ignorar valores repetidos de un array en C?

Tags: c, array

El problema a resolver en sí es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo tener resuelto la mayor parte del problema, aunque ya no pude resolver eso que estoy preguntando, pues al final me imprime 10 cuando deberían ser 8. Entonces quisiera saber cómo lograr que no me cuente esos múltiplos que están repetidos pero no sé cómo lograrlo.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
        int size,size2,n,a,b,multiplos, iguales;
        scanf("%d",&size);
        printf(" tamanio: %d \n",size);
        if(0<size && size<=1000){
            int array[size];
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                scanf("%d",&n);
                printf(" numero %d: %d \n",i+1,n);
                if(0<n && n<=2^31-1){
                    array[i]=n;             
                }           
            }
            scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
            printf(" limite de %d a %d \n",a,b);        
            if(0<a && a<=b && b<=2^31-1 && b-a<=10^6){
                size2=b-a+1;        
                int array2[size2];
                for(int j=0;j<size2;j++){
                    array2[j]=a;
                    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                        int multi=array[i]*array2[j];                   
                        if (multi>=a && multi<=b){
                            printf("%d x %d = %d \n",array[i],array2[j],array[i]*array2[j]);                        
                            multiplos=multiplos+1;                      
                        }                                       
                    }                                                                   
                    a=a+1;                                              
                }       
            }       
        }
        printf("%d",multiplos); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu error esta en la forma en que recorres tus valores **n**.

Ademas `if(0<a && a<=b && b<=2^31-1 && b-a<=10^6)`  no es necesario, aun peor lo que hiciste no es correcto, el simbolo `^` indica un **OR exclusivo bit a bit** cosa que esta mal en tu if, en todo caso si deseas la operacion de potencia deberias de utilizar [pow](http://www.carlospes.com/curso_de_lenguaje_c/01_08_01_03_la_funcion_pow.php).

Para ayudarte a entender mejor las preguntas cosas como `0<a<=b<=2^(31-1), b-a <= 10^6` son solo reglas para poder crear tus variables, ejemplo: cuando dicen `2^(31-1)` se traduce a que solo es necesario un **int** para trabajar tu algoritmo no es necesario realizar in **if** para controlar este dato.

Bueno ahora te brindo una pequeña ayuda para tu programa, Intenta lo siguiente:

```
int aux=0;
if(a>b){
    aux=b;
    b=a;
    a=aux;
}
for(int i=a;i<=b;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
        if (i%array[j]==0){                     
            multiplos=multiplos+1;                      
            break;
        }                                       
    }                                                   
}
```

Codigo que vendria despues de ingresar todos tus datos de entrada, y al final imprimes **multiplos** para mostrar la respusta.

Comment: Gracias por las correcciones y el código brindado. Lo implementaré en cuanto pueda y avisaré si quedó resuelto :)